# Entity Framework: Similar table names causing problems when pluralized (Database First)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two tables that I can't rename in SQL server at this point. One is tblVideo and the other is tblVideos (unfortunate naming I know, don't get me started). The table tblVideo has already been imported with pluralization on. I want to import tblVideos now, but when I do it names the table tblVideo1 and I absolutely do not want to use a numbered table name.

I renamed the entity to tblVehicleVideoClip in the edmx UI.

[image]

When I pull the entity it still uses the name tblVideo1 (or tblVideos1 if plural). Only the resulting object that's returned is named tblVehicleVideoClip.

```
List<tblVehicleVideoClip> list = db.tblVideos1.ToList();
```

How do I get the db.tvlVideos1 to instead use db.tblVehicleVideoClips? I keep trying to edit the edmx file, but when I do the edmx display says that the xml was modified and it can no longer show me the nice UI display.

Comment: Ah, your comment gave me the clue I needed. Entity Set name was the field that needed to be changed. Thank you.  And yes, I agree those tbl* prefixes really need to go. If you post that in the answer to the question I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the entity name in the EDMX designer, but also the entity set name, i.e. the name of the `DbSet` property in the context:

[image]